# How fetch and display data on vue component with laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel, vue.js

I have a created a form in vue component. How can I fetch the data from database and fill the drop-down

Database table details as follows (table name is : users) and colums ID,FullName,DOB

Comment: you have a frontend now you need a backend you can make this using laravel and expose some URI's form where you can fetch the data.

Comment: Could you provide some code example for this

Answer (score 1):

**front end and the server side code talks via HTTP requests.**

//suppose this is the view

```
//now this function is in your vue which will fetch the data from an URI
functionToFetchData(uri){
 fetch(uri){
  //do your stuff here like checking fetched data and assigning then to vairalbe
 }
```

}

//suppose this is your laravel server in php

```
//suppose this is your exposed API URI 
when user fetch :/api/uri then return 'some data'
now this some data will be returned to the front end which is in vue which you can show to the user.
```

NOTE : front end technology like vue do not talks with the database directly instead they talk with the server side code which in your case you'll write in laravel and laravel code will talk with the databse which you'll write in php.